# Перестал работать PHP код, который работал раньше. Что делать?

Tags: php

Название звучит смешно, знаю. Но всё на самом деле так и есть. Суть в том, что есть код и его довольно много. Раньше всё работало, а теперь просто взяло и перестало. В логах периодически возникают на пустом месте ошибки наподобие "syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)" или "syntax error, unexpected '*переменнаянейм*' (T_VARIABLE)". Перед строками с ошибками есть точка с запятой, никаких ошибок тоже нету, я не раз проверял. Но самое комичное в этой ситуации то, что помогает мне замена этой строки (копирование-вставляние) той же самой строкой из другого файла. Но не все строки можно найти в других файлах и после "исправления" одной ошибки появляется другая. Что делать? Я нормальный вообще?

```
if($_GET['mode'] == 'uploading') {

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // 65 строка, в которой ошибка "unexpected '$extension' (T_VARIABLE)"
if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
}
// далее идёт продолжение
```

Comment: кэш используется, типа opcache? Другой софт, зловред?

Comment: @Deadooshka опачки. phpinfo выдал, что есть Zend OPcache и он работает. А что это даёт?

Comment: У меня была схожая бага - часто вылетала 500-я на страницах которые только что грузились.  И помогало именно исправление какой-нибудь строки на ту же самую. Как только исправишь - работает первый раз, а затем снова 500-я.  И действительно глянули в сторону кеширования, отключили для теста стоявший APC Cache - и все стало прекрасно. Так что может у вас что-то похожее.

Comment: скорее всего глюки оперативной памяти

Comment: Можно включить [логи](http://php.net/manual/ru/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.error-log) опкеша и понаблюдать. Поиграть с настройками, связанными с памятью.

Comment: @u_mulder отключил опкеш. Не помогло. Мда.

Comment: @Deadooshka а где вообще эти логи лежат? Я их что-то не нахожу.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас на сервере PHP обновился, например для 5.6 версии обязательно нужно создавать переменную прежде чем присвоить что либо иначе не ошибку выдаст.

Comment: @bemulima я вас не очень понимаю. Разве $var = 'string'; - неверно?

Comment: не, скорее зловред или глюки железа. Сравнивайте хеши файлов до глюка и после. Если одинаковые, то либо модуль памяти сбоит, либо какой-то вирус. С переменными в 5.6 ничего такого не изменилось.

Comment: @Deadooshka у меня нету хешей файлов до этого случая :(

Comment: проверьте глючный скрипт через CLI `php -l <file.php>`

Comment: @Deadooshka, 

`//для PHP < 5.4 здесь нужно объявить переменную $var=0; 
if(...) 
{
    $var = 1;
}
...
if($var===1) //На PHP > 5.4 работает, а на PHP < 5.4 дает ошибку
{ 
    ... 
}`

Comment: @bemulima, для таких случаев есть `isset()` и `empty()`. В плане ошибок при обращении к необъявленным переменным ничего не изменилось. Показ ошибок можно убрать в конфиге.

Comment: @Deadooshka, И, что если отключить ошибки в конфиге, код всё равно будет работать? На счет `isset()` и `empty()`, я в PHP < 5.4 не использовал, теперь везде использую, как только PHP обновили на сервере.

Comment: @bemulima да, будет null. Убрать ошибки можно ещё с @ `@$var`.

Comment: @Deadooshka вот что выдала проверка: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$extension' (T_VARIABLE) in posting.php on line 64
Errors parsing posting.php`

Comment: @Deadooshka обновил вопрос и добавил код со строкой, где ошибка.

Comment: тут ничего нет, вы в hex редакторе откройте чтобы все символы видеть. Вообще конечно нужно админским софтом отследить, если зловредное что-то.

Comment: @Deadooshka проверил всё ClamAV - вроде как ничего нет. Открыл файл в hex-редакторе. Что теперь? Я вижу огромное количество непонятной бурды.

Comment: @Deadooshka [вот скриншот этой строки из hex редактора](http://puu.sh/i6aqb/6dcc80b0c0.png). Как это поможет?

Comment: надо всё видеть между `{` и `$ext...`. там должны быть только горизонтальные пробельные символы. Если и там нормально, то я пас.

Comment: да, ещё там перенос строки же... Короче php реагирует на какой-то левый символ, который не отображается в обычном редакторе.

Comment: @Deadooshka [вот](http://puu.sh/i6ctl/24dfc14133.png)

Comment: @Deadooshka чудеса какие-то. Попробовал переместить строки. Проблема именно в этой самой строке, где находится переменная $extention (убрал пробелы, на неё переместилось следующее после переменной if). Омг, что делать?

Comment: @Deadooshka я разобрался. Напишу ответ.

Comment: да, там левые символы С2A0, и PHP на них ругается. Удали их перед переменной в hex-редакторе. Как они там оказались хз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя день мучений ответ был найден. Итак, вот что нужно сделать, если с вашим кодом происходит чертовщина:

- Сначала скопируйте свой код, вставьте его на phpformatter.com и нажмите "Format". Если будет ошибка, то вы узнаете об этом.
- В случае ошибки найдите любой инструмент, который позволит вам убрать все отступы строк. Мне помог codeanywhere.com (В интерфейсе нажмите Indent left).
- Далее скопируйте код и вставьте снова на phpformatter.com и нажмите "Format". После этих действий код успешно был отформатирован. Значит, проблема исправлена (+ вы получаете красивый код; мне эти шаги помогли)

Надеюсь, это поможет кому-нибудь.

Comment: Ну или можете покопаться в hex-редакторах.